# Java wrapper around Map-like implementation

Tags: java, dictionary, bundle

I am looking for a stable and easy-to-use implementation of a wrapper around Java's Map interface. Basically, I'd like the functionality of Android's [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) class so I can do this:

`float  getFloat(String key, float defaultValue)`
`void   putShort(String key, short value)`
`String     getString(String key, String defaultValue)`
`void   putInt(String key, int value)`

and so on. I've seen [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) class, but I'd like more than `getObject` and `getString` methods.

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: sounds trivial, have you tried implementing it yourself?

Comment: The implementation itself should not be too hard, however, before I do it myself and spend considerate portion of my time (which I don't have) to write and test such library, I'd like to see if there is a stable, maintained implementation that I can use.

Comment: You can implement a Map yourself OR if you want to create a wrapper You can create it. Have multiple maps for each type (Int , float and String) internally.

Comment: I DO know how to make a wrapper. However, I do not want to reinvent the wheel if such lib already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See apache-commons configuration:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/

in particular the [map-based configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/configuration/MapConfiguration.html).

Comment: I've taken a look at it, and it is more lightweight than ResourceBundle, however, the only value-retrieval method is `getProperty(String key) : Object`, and I do not want to hard-cast every single value I pull out of it.

Comment: That's not correct, there are many typed getters, see the methods in http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/AbstractConfiguration.html

Comment: You are right, I've checked the map-based config link you provided. Answer accepted :D